# Do takeoffs and landings in a Pilatus PC-12 count for currency in a Piper Archer?

Tags: faa-regulations, currency, pic

I just read [this](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&r=SECTION&n=14y2.0.1.1.2.1.1.36):

> No person my act as PIC of an aircraft carrying passengers unless, within the preceding 90 days, he/she has made three takeoffs and landings as the sole manipulator of the controls in an aircraft of the **same category, class, and type (if required)**

Does this mean that you are legal to take passengers in an Archer if you have logged three takeoffs and landings in the past 90 days in a Pilatus PC-12?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Category: Yes, both are "airplanes" as opposed to rotorcraft or gliders.

Class: Yes, both are single engine land planes, as opposed to multi-engined or sea planes.

Type: Yes, neither aircraft requires a type rating (both are under 12,500 lb max takeoff weight, neither is powered by a turbojet)

So the Piper Archer and Pilatus PC-12 qualify as currency for each other per this regulation.